# A good book on Brownian motion

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Can you suggest me a good book on Brownian motion, where it is introduced as a limit of measures on polish spaces like $C[0,1]$ and subsequently stochastic calculus is discussed?

Comment: What do you mean by "as a limit of measures on polish spaces like $C[0,1]$? Are you interested in the canonical Brownian motion (i.e. BM defined on $C[0,1]$) or do you want to consider Brownian motion on more general spaces?

Comment: I am interested in Canonical BM

Answer (score 1):

The monograph [*Brownian Motion - An Introduction to Stochastic Processes* by René Schilling and Lothar Partzsch](http://motapa.de/brownian_motion/index.shtml) discusses canonical Brownian motion (chapter 4) and contains several chapters on stochastic calculus (stochastic integrals with respect to Brownian motion, stochastic differential equations, applications, ...)